# Is it possible to convert a Netgear D500 N150 Wi-Fi Modem Router into a standalone router/ access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I was using a broadband which required a modem-router (Netgear D500 N150 Wi-Fi Modem Router) with an ADSL port.
Recently I switched over to a Broadband which requires only a router. Is it possible to use the Netgear D500 N150 as router alone?

Comment: Does your new broadband not require a username / password combination to login to the internet? I mean - just plugging the broadband cable on to ur laptop makes it connected to the internet without using any password?

Comment: It does need but, first I got to login into the address/webpage provided by the ISP to enter the credentials and then it allows me to access the internet. The login credentials are not embedded in the modem level as it was done before.

Comment: I prefer that you read the user manual provided by @Romeo in the answer below. If you have specific questions after that, please edit ur question and we will see how to guide you through

Comment: I'll do that and revert. Thanks Romeo and Prasanna.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and it is described very well in to the router [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/D500/D500-D1500_UM_22Aug2014.pdf)

Page 19, point 12:

**Change the default connection method:**

a. Select ADVANCED > Setup > WAN Setup

b. From the WAN Preference menu, select Must use Ethernet WAN